# Toolkit class in java

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create custom cursors for JButtons in Java.
So I use the Toolkit class.
However Toolkit methods somehow fail to load my image. Here is my code:

```
public class ButtonPerso extends JButton{

 private Toolkit toolkit; 

 private Cursor myCursor; 

 private Point hotSpot;

 private Image image;

 public ButtonPerso(String label) {

  super(label);

  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

  image = toolkit.createImage("candle.gif" );

  hotSpot = new Point(0, 0);  

  //myCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Candle");
  myCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Candle");

  addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      //setCursor (Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
      setCursor(myCursor);
    }
      }
  );

 }
}
```

Everytime I get this **error**:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI.ButtonPerso.<init>(ButtonPerso.java:36)
    at GUI.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:61)
    at GUI.Fenetre.<init>(Fenetre.java:18)
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

So I guess there is something happening with these exception: `IndexOutOfBoundsException,HeadlessException.` I tried to locate the problem:

```
try {
  myCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(Menu.image, hotSpot, "Candle");
  }
  catch (HeadlessException h) {

  }

  catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException i) {
    System.out.println("index except");
  }
```

But I still get the same warnings, I don't know what to do can you give me a hand ? Perhaps it comes from my image

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this line:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

You'll want to write:

```
toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

Otherwise `toolkit` will remain `null`, and you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call a method on it.

Comment: Oh boy... Can't believe I've lost an hour on that :( Thank you very much Jesper!

Answer (score 1):

```
private Toolkit toolkit; 
\\ toolkit is not initialized and hence it is a null reference.
\\ Below line will throw NullPointerException
image = toolkit.createImage("candle.gif" );

\\ You need to assign the toolkit first.
toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```